# Will Flash Builder let me build framework-less application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, sdk, builder

I want to create a pure as3 (without any mxml) web application using flash builder.

The problem is that I don't want to use the flex framework nor the AirSDK - because I rely on playerglobal.swc, and some uicomponents that I exported from a FLA into a swc. Unfortunately, it seems that the IDE forces you to pick the flex framework or the airSDK.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: create actionscript project then there is no any mxml

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e972ff2927b12e1411968f-7fff.html#WSc5cd04c102ae3e972ff2927b12e1411968f-7ff7

Create ActionScript projects

> Create an ActionScript application for the Web or Desktop by following
>   these steps:
>
> ```
> Select File > New > ActionScript Project.
>
> Enter a project name and location.
>
> The default location is the current workspace.
>
> Select either Web or Desktop for the application type.
>
> This project uses the AIR SDK 3.4 by default. Click Check For Updates to check and download an updated version of the AIR SDK if
> ```
>
> available.
>
> ```
> Click Next.
>
> Specify Build Paths.
>
> For more information, see Build paths, native extensions, and other project configuration options.
>
> Click Finish.
> ```
>
> For more information on coding in ActionScript, see the ActionScript
>   Developer's Guide.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was very clear.  The problem is that I HAVE to use an AIR SDK when I select 'Actionscript Project'. I want to use Flash Builder for a pure AS3 project that only uses Flash's playerglobal library and the uicomponents that I export as a swc from Flash. Is that possible?